# Python syntax error...cannot see the error!

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm very new to python and have created a script for enabling a user to list file types in a workspace making use of the parameters function in ArcGIS so it's more user friendly. However I cannot get the script to work...I am struggling to finish the script off can anyone lend a hand?

Python reports the syntax error in line 36 "f.close()" there is no white space around it so am struggling to see whats wrong...can you? Or what am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
env.workspace = ("C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb")
ws = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
option = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputFilePath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

dsList = []

if option == "List Feature Classes":
    featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Tables":
    tables = arcpy.ListTables(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Rasters":
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Workspaces":
    workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Files":
    files = arcpy.ListFiles(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)

f = open(outputFilePath, 'w') 

for item in dsList:

f.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a body in your for loop:

```
f = open(outputFilePath, 'w') 

for item in dsList: << This is a empty for block
   # need something here

f.close()
```

I think you will also get error when you run it because `tables` isn't defined in a lot of cases

```
if option == "List Feature Classes":
    featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(ws)
    for table in tables: << where is tables defined
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Tables":
    tables = arcpy.ListTables(ws)
    for table in tables:
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Rasters":
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters(ws)
    for table in tables: << where is tables defined
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Workspaces":
    workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces(ws)
    for table in tables: << where is tables defined
        dsList.append(table)
elif option == "List Files":
    files = arcpy.ListFiles(ws)
    for table in tables: << where is tables defined
        dsList.append(table)
```

Comment: Would {print to (outputFilePath)} work for printing to results to the defined outputFilePath?

Comment: Ah yes...tables isn't defined

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to write something to this file:

```
for item in dsList:
    f.write(item + "\n")
f.close()
```